# Heat Sink considerations for thermionic generators

Tags: material-science, thermoelectricity

I recently read an article describing thermionic generation. I am considering  building a TG for a science fair experiment. I was thinking about surrounding my heat source with a spherical emitter and placing my collector outside of the case where I can use the ambient air as a heat sink. The load will then be placed in the circuit path. IYO am I on the right path?

Comment: @schuberm makes the comment "Can you provide some numbers about the system? Efficiency, power consumption, etc..".

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance I assume the efficiency will be fairly low. This is a proof of concept so all I need is an output voltage of 3 or 4 VDC. I am concerned that (other than the line-loss) the distance to the collector  might prove to be a problem or that a spherical emitter might some how short itself resulting in zero output.